# Being deaf and still produce music, how is that possible

Tags: technique, learning, performing, hearing

Does anybody knows [Sean Forbes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sean_Forbes)? He is deaf, but produces music, like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E5l-2Jo14cQ). According to sources he can also play guitar and drums, how is this possible? Also check out the story of [Patric Costello](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/meet-the-partially-deaf-musician-sharing-the-joy-of-homemade-music_us_58c1a530e4b0ed71826af3fd).

How is all this possible? Are they completely deaf, do they just feel the music (vibrating air) on their skin/stomach? Whats a meaning of a melody for them? Or of harmony?

Comment: Ask Ludwig, he did it.

Comment: There are rules of music theory can provide rules to follow. Also, there are people that become deaf that have internalized aural training well enough that they can still "hear" it.... still i would have to image it would be unsatifying to compose a piece and not hear it for real

Answer (score 8):

He seems to wear a hearing aid, so he isn't profoundly deaf.  According to Wikipedia he's 90% deaf.  His parents bought him a drum set after noting him react to music on the radio.  (Just what the world needs, another deaf drummer :-)

Beethoven went deaf in later life.  Whether profoundly deaf or not, I don't know.

And there's this lady, who as well as having a successful musical career, seems to have thoroughly enjoyed her personal life!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evelyn_Glennie

Comment: Isn't 'deaf drummer' tautologous?

Comment: Pardon?
.........................

Comment: Tim jokingly means that drummers "strongly" tend to go deaf from inevitably playing too loudly too often.

Comment: @Dekkadeci - did it really need an explanation? It's a known and accepted fact that some drummers have their hearing affected by the volume they produce - and the viscious spiral of loudness that it often produces in some bands. Been there too often...

Comment: The story of Evelyin is impressive too, but what I do not get: I saw this TED-Talk of her: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IU3V6zNER4g and in year way of speaking she does not sound like a deaf person, for example Sean also speaks in a way (if you hear interviews) that seems to be typical of deaf people...

Comment: @Tim, given Laurence Payne's "Pardon?", I believed an explanation was warranted.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia on Symphony No. 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symphony_No._9_(Beethoven)), Beethoven was almost totally deaf and couldn't hear the orchestra he "conducted"... and also the famous "still conducting while the symphony was already over"

Comment: Evelyn lost her hearing at age 12, Sean before age 1.  Hence the difference in speech I expect.

Comment: @Dekkadeci - that 'Pardon.................' was probably because Laurence has worked with more than a few drummers...

Answer (score 4):

The musician's ear worm [Audiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordon_music_learning_theory) might be what you are looking for.  My brother in law can hear the music in his head solely by reading the score.  I'm trying to develop that skill.

Answer (score 1):

If you go deaf early in life you can't understand true melody and harmony. You can feel vibrations, but that's not an acoustic experience. I don't know about the guys you mentioned, but let me explain a composer's case.

Beethoven (and Faure) went deaf later in his life. A composer learns the harmonic and melodic patterns and just knows how they sound in their head. When they read or write music they don't need to hear it - they know how it sounds.

Try it yourself with a reading book - read the words in your head, you can actually "hear" them since you already know what they sound like. You are familiar with the sounds produced by the combinations of letters. A good deaf composer can write music just as well as a deaf writer can write word-based works. Depends on how proficient you are with music, come up with a melody in your head (don't sing or play it), take a sheet of paper and write it down. That's it. Deafness doesn't hinder you that much once you have a good image of how music sound.

Players on the other hand can't play if they are completely deaf. There are many minute pitch and tempo corrections your brain does "automatically" (to some extent) by hearing the players around you, or even the previous note you played. Don't know about drummers, but I have a feeling even they need to listen to what's going on around them.

So: (experienced) composers - yes, conductors and players - no.

Comment: "If you go deaf early in life you can't understand true melody and harmony. You can feel vibrations, but that's not an acoustic experience." Actually, harmony simply is the relationships between vibrations of sound waves; so harmony is just feeling vibrations, like the 2:1 relationship between octaves. You can feel the music plenty without the assistance of your ears in a way that's not intuitive, but very real none the less.

Comment: So you're telling Evelyn Glennie that she can't do what she does do, user1803551

Comment: @LaurencePayne I wrote specifically that drummers are an exception, though I'm pretty sure it hurts them as well.

Comment: @SpiderShlong Both harmony and melody are just wave bundles, but feeling the vibrations with the body is not a substitute for the brain receiving them. Not practically, because you won't get the level of accuracy you need, and not neurologically.

Comment: User1803551 - I think that is entirely your opinion, and incorrect. There are those who say it is the same, and that in the brain it is the same. Have you got any references to support your assertion?

Comment: @DrMayhem Which part? Most of it is and has been the consensus and has everyday ample proof.